# Configuração datasource

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, wildfly, datasource

Galera estou com uma aplicação java rodando no wildFly 8 e utilizando Sql Server, o problema que estou passando no momento é que chega um momento a aplicação me retorna falando que não foi possível abrir a conexão, verifiquei no código e todas as funcionalidades que realiza transações no banco estão sendo fechadas, um rapaz da infra me informou que o problema se encontra no wildfly que não está matando as conexões, a solução proposta por ele é definir o tempo de vida da conexão dentro do wildfly.

Gostaria da ajuda dos senhores para sanar esse problema.
obs: O banco está configurado para aceitar no máximo 5 conexões.

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironcajamar/schema">
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/focusDS1" pool-name="focusDS1">
<connection-url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://dsdb03:1433/sis</connection-url>
<driver-class>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
<driver>jtds-1.2.4.jar</driver>
<pool>
    <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
 </pool>
 <security>
    <user-name>XXXXX</user-name>
    <password>XXXXX</password>
 </security> 
     <validation>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
     </validation>
    <timeout>
      <idle-timeout-minutes>1</idle-timeout-minutes>
      <allocation-retry>6</allocation-retry>
    </timeout>
</datasource>
</datasources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que o problema esteja aqui:

```
<max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
```

Se o banco de dados está configurado para aceitar até 5 conexões e você define que pode ter até 100 conexões abertas no seu pool, a aplicação vai tentar abrir todas estas conexões em determinado momento e não conseguirá (pois o banco de dados não permitirá), causando o problema.

Para resolver, defina o max-pool-size para 5:

```
<max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
```